# To determine a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

A question of my book & i find some difficulty in solving it

The only singularities of a single valued function f(z) are poles of order 2 & 1 at z=1 & z=2 with residue of these poles 1 & 3 respectively . If $f(0)=\frac{3}{2}$ & f(-1)=1 then determine the function.

My try is that i let function $f(z)=\left(\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}\right)$

Let the partial decomposition be

$f(z)$=$\left(\frac{b}{z-1}\right)$+$\left(\frac{b_2}{(z-1)^2}\right)$+$\left(\frac{b'_1}{z-2}\right)$

now if i am correct then coefficient of first term in laurents expansion about $z=1(or 2)$ is equal to the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=1(or 2)$

hence $b=1$ & $b'_1=2$

now what i should do further to get value of $b_2$.I am still working on the problem.

please help

Comment: On what domain is $f$ supposed to be meromorphic?

Comment: the function is meromorphic on whole complex plane

Comment: Then it's still underspecified.

There is a unique such function $f_0$ that is meromorphic on the whole sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ satisfying the conditions, and adding any entire function that vanishes in $0$ and $-1$ to $f_0$ produces another function that is meromorphic on the whole complex plane satisfying the conditions.

Comment: To solve in descriptive method i should have some stepwise procedure.Now i am working on the relation of residue of a function & its coefficient.if one have any hint plz suggest

Comment: Hint: partial fraction decomposition. That's easier than your approach.

Comment: O.k i"ll solve the problem & share it within half an hour .plz stay there